# Making one marker adjustable at a time

Tags: leaflet, javascript

This screenshot is an example of what I have to do :
[image: An example of what I have to do]

**This picture was taken on a different and older version of what I have now, since all of the present images were NOT markers bound to the map**

After my images became elements of the map, I had to rewrite this script :

```
var angle = 0;
var width = 60;
var height = 40;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 65){ //"A" key
        angle-=5;
        left();
    };
    if(e.which == 69){ //"E" key
        angle+=5;
        right();
    };
    if(e.which == 83){ //"S" key
        height+=5;
        smaller();
    };
    if(e.which == 90){ //"Z" key
        height-=5;
        bigger();
    };
    if(e.which == 81){ //"Q" key
        width-=5;
        thinner();
    };
    if(e.which == 68){ //"D" key
        width+=5;
        wider();
    };
});

function left(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.transform = "rotate("+angle+"deg)";};
function right(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.transform = "rotate("+angle+"deg)";};
function smaller(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.height =  height + 'px'};
function bigger(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.height = height + 'px'};
function wider(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.width = width + 'px'};
function thinner(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.width = width + 'px'};
```

and it was working the way I wanted to : having only one image that can rotate, can be resized at a time.

Where as now, I'm using this script (with leaflet.rotatedMarker for the rotation):

```
var opened = 0;
var angle = 0;
var markerNumber = 0;
var divider = 0;
var markerList = [];
var width = 60;
var height = 40;
var marker = L.marker(coordinates, {icon: L.icon({iconUrl: imagePath, iconSize: [60,40]}),draggable: true}).bindPopup('Use A, E, Z, Q, S or D to adjust me !').addTo(mymap);
divider += 1;
markerList += markerNumber;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 65){angle-=5/divider;setAngle();}; //"A" key
    if(e.which == 69){angle+=5/divider;setAngle();}; //"E" key
    if(e.which == 90){height-=5/divider;smaller();}; //"Z" key
    if(e.which == 81){ width-=5/divider;thinner();}; //"Q" key
    if(e.which == 83){height+=5/divider;taller();}; //"S" key
    if(e.which == 68){width+=5/divider;wider();}; //"D" key
});
marker.on('popupopen', function(e){
    opened = 1;
    if(opened == 1){
        $('.leaflet-marker-icon').addClass('adjustable');
        marker.setRotationOrigin('center center');
    };
});
marker.on('popupclose', function(e){
    opened -= 1;
    markerNumber +=1 ;
    if(opened == 0){
        $('.leaflet-marker-icon').removeClass('adjustable');
    };
});

function setAngle(){marker.setRotationAngle(angle)};
function smaller(){$('.adjustable')[markerNumber].style.height = height + 'px'};
function taller(){$('.adjustable')[markerNumber].style.height = height + 'px'};
function wider(){$('.adjustable')[markerNumber].style.width = width + 'px'};
function thinner(){$('.adjustable')[markerNumber].style.width = width + 'px'};
};
```

I identified two or three problems:

- The `setRotationAngle` impact ALL markers on the map **[FIXED]**
- The `getElementsById('rotate')` only makes the FIRST marker resizable **[FIXED]**
- after each `popupclose` :

  1. the `width` and `height` vlaue wil automatically be increased by 5 **[FIXED]**
  2. I can still rotate my markers, which isn't what I want **[FIXED]**

**What I need:**

- Using `popupopen` : having only the marker bound to the opened popup resizable and spinnable. **DONE**
- Using `popupclose` : removing the resizable and spinnable functions of the marker bound to the closed popup. **DONE**

All I'm trying to do now is to remove the `rotationOrigin` option when I close the popup

I know this sound extremely familiar to what I've asked before, but now, I'll need to apply this to multiple markers

Comment: If you have a solution to your question, please describe it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**What I did to make everything work** (compared to the previous script)

I added a `setAdjustments(true OR false)` inside my popupop event like so :

```
marker.on('popupopen', function(e){
    var Adjustments = setAdjustements(false);
    if(Adjustments == true){
        $('.leaflet-marker-icon').addClass('adjustable');
        marker.setRotationOrigin('center center');
    };
});
marker.on('popupclose', function(e){
    markerNumber +=1;
    $('.leaflet-marker-icon').removeClass('adjustable');
    var Adjustments = setAdjustements(true);
});
function setAdjustements(Adjustments){
    if(Adjustments == false){
        NewAdjustments = true;
        return NewAdjustments;
    };
    if(Adjustments == true){
        NewAdjustments = false;
        return NewAdjustments;
    };
};
```

I aslo added a `isPopupOpen()` test inside my `setAngle()` to allow rotation if the popup is open, like so :

```
function setAngle(){
    if(marker.isPopupOpen(marker) == true){
        marker.setRotationAngle(angle);
    };
};
```

About the `getElementById('rotate')`, I replaced it with a `getElementsByClassName('adjustable')[markerNumber]`, with the value `markerNumber` incrementing by 1 each time a popup has been closed (which leads to other problems, I'll work on that on my own)